# Python OpenCV single letter recognition

Tags: python, opencv, image-recognition

I'm trying with OpenCV to recognize a single letter using the webcam.
Only with two letters or more is working.
There is any chance to OpenCV support single letter recognition?

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import pytesseract
import threading
from PIL import Image

class EyeWatcher:

    #(...)

    def work(self, words, callback):
        lastresult = ''
        cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

        self.__class__.isOpened = cap.isOpened()

        while(self.__class__.isOpened):
            ret, capimg = cap.read()

            img = cv2.cvtColor(capimg, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

            kernel = np.ones((1, 1), np.uint8)
            img = cv2.dilate(img, kernel, iterations=1)
            img = cv2.erode(img, kernel, iterations=1)

            arr = Image.fromarray(img)
            result = pytesseract.image_to_string(arr)

            if result and lastresult != result:
                if not words or any(result in s for s in words):
                    lastresult = result
                    callback(result)

        cap.release()
```

The call:

```
import eyewatcher

def hunted(r):    
    if r == 'H':
        print("Hi")
    # (...)
    else:
        print("nothing to do with you...")

eyewatcher.EyeWatcher.open(['A5', 'A4', 'H', 'S', 'U'], hunted)
#(...)
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can tell tesseract, that you expect, that there will be only a single character in the image. Check out the [docs](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/wiki/Command-Line-Usage) and look for psm and oem mode.

The [definition](https://github.com/madmaze/pytesseract/blob/master/src/pytesseract.py#L94) of image_to_string states that you can pass commandline options to it.

Your config string should look like this

```
'--tessdata-dir "/home/rvq/github/tesseract/tessdata/" --psm 10  --oem 2 '
```

---

I implemented a quick minimal test and it worked very well.

**code:**

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import pytesseract
from PIL import Image


def work(image):
    lastresult = ''
    image = cv2.imread(image)

    img = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    kernel = np.ones((1, 1), np.uint8)
    img = cv2.dilate(img, kernel, iterations=1)
    img = cv2.erode(img, kernel, iterations=1)
    tessdata_dir_config = '--tessdata-dir "/home/rvq/github/tesseract/tessdata/" --psm 10  --oem 2 '
    arr = Image.fromarray(img)
    result = pytesseract.image_to_string(arr, config = tessdata_dir_config)
    print(result)

work('./00001.png')
```

---

**Image 00001.png:**

[image]

---

result on commandline: 0